# Definite article_(the) books you have

Tags: grammar

Context: a teacher is giving some instructions for a homework to students and tells them
"You should use online resources and (the) books you have."

I think that "the" is optional here. Right?

Comment: *You should use online resources and **any** books you have [which are relevant to this homework task].*

Answer (score 1):

It is optional, but it slightly changes the meaning of the sentence.

**Using the definite article "the"** implies that you should read specific books that you have (now).

**Not using the definite article** implies that you should *generally* read books that you have (or may have in future).

There is, of course, a bit of overlap in those uses and word emphasis can help with that.

Comment: If so, the version with “the” is more appropriate to use here. Do you find my sentence with “the” natural to use here?

Comment: The version with _the_ is more natural, as it presumably refers to a particular set of books.